# Regex correct pattern matching conditions in java jdbc

Tags: java, regex, jdbc

I want to match with strings which is alphanumeric as well as which has special characters `-`, `/` and also white spaces

For example: If the string is `Motorola C168/CC168i-1` , it should match

But when I am using following regular expression, its not matching it right. So, what is the correct condition?

```
if (line.matches("[A-Za-z0-9 \\/\\-]+$") {
    .....
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the string has no other whitespace inside? Also, you do not need `$` with `.matches()`. And no need escaping `/` and no need escaping the hyphen at the end of the character class. Use just `[A-Za-z0-9 /-]+`, or - to include any whitespace - `[A-Za-z0-9\\s/-]+`.

Comment: Could you copy the exact string that failed?

Answer (score 0):

You need look aheads, one for each required char, anchored to start:

```
if (line.matches("(?=.* )(?=.*/)(?=.*-)[A-Za-z0-9]+")
```

BTW, Java ain't JavaScript; no need to escape slashes.